# Error when parsing JSON data (Swift 4 Playground)

Tags: swift4, xcode9, swift-playground

My Swift Playground keeps returning

> Error: The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct
>   format."

and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Below is my code.

JSON Sample Data:

```
{
            "meta": {
                "name":"Tour of Honor Bonus Listing",
                "version":"18.1.4"
            },
            "bonuses": [
            {
            "bonusCode":"AZ1",
            "category":"ToH",
            "name":"Anthem Tour of Honor Memorial",
            "value":1,
            "city":"Anthem",
            "state":"AZ",
            "flavor":"Flavor Text Goes Here"
            }
            ]
        }
```

Playground Code:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

struct JsonFile: Codable {
    struct Meta: Codable {
        let name: String
        let version: String
    }
    struct JsonBonuses: Codable {
        let bonusCode: String
        let category: String
        let name: String
        let value: Int
        let city: String
        let state: String
        let flavor: String
    }
    let meta: Meta
    let bonuses: [JsonBonuses]

}

let url = URL(string: "http://www.tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json")!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
    }
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
        print("Error: invalid HTTP response code")
        PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
    }
    guard let data = data else {
        print("Error: missing data")
        PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
    }

    // feel free to uncomment this for debugging data
    // print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let posts = try decoder.decode([JsonFile].self, from: data)

        print(posts.map { $0.meta.name })
        PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
    }
    catch {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
    }
    }.resume()
```

I assume I have something in my Struct incorrect, but I can't figure out what it is.

(This paragraph is to make the submission tool happy because it says I have too much code and not enough other details. Apparently being direct and succinct is not compatible with the submission scanning function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struct is correct but the root object is not an array (remove the brackets)

```
let posts = try decoder.decode(JsonFile.self, from: data)
print(posts.bonuses.map{$0.name})
```

Comment: If I may ask a follow up question: Say I want to print the version of the JSON file instead of a bonus name. When I change the print to `print(posts.meta.map{$0.version})` I get an error saying "value of type 'JsonFile.Meta' has no member 'map'". If I remove the .map from that, then it gives "cannot call value of non-function type 'JsonFile.Meta'"

Comment: `map` is for arrays. As the value for key `meta` is not an array you have to write `print(posts.meta.version)`